# Getting multiple columns on a KRL stats_query with the gem

Tags: krl

I'd like to use the `krl stats_query` function of the gem to get a table with multiple dimensions in it. At the moment, I can only figure out how to pass one dimension, one KPI, and one range:

```
krl stats_query -k rules_fired -d day_of_week -r last_three_months
```

If I wanted to have the report include `rules_fired` and `brse`, how would I do that? I've tried comma-separated lists (e.g., `-k brse,rules_fired`) and passing the `-k` option multiple times (e.g., `-k brse -k rules_fired`), and neither works.

If it's possible to do that with KPIs, can it also be done with dimensions? For example, I might want a report with the `ddmonyyyy` and the corresponding `day_of_week`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in the source code for the gem. See (at time of writing) line 209 of [cli.rb](https://github.com/kynetx/krl/blob/master/lib/cli.rb). The solution is to **space-separate** the desired columns, like this:

```
krl stats_query -k brse rules_fired -d day_of_week -r last_three_months.
```